# capybara: mysterious 'element at X no longer present in the DOM'

Tags: capybara-webkit

I have written cucumber test scenario's that are tested with webkit and a firefox driver. In firefox the tests all pass, but with webkit one of them fails with error

```
  Element at 40 no longer present in the DOM (Capybara::Webkit::NodeNotAttachedError)
  /home/r/project/share/support/actions.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in follow_link_in_new_tab'
 /home/r/project/duplo/share/support/actions.rb:10:in `with_scope'................
```

This happens during the execution of a routine that is triggered by test step 'When I follow "Linkname". Strangely enough, most of the times this code works perfect, but in one case I get this 'no longer present error'.

The routine performs this:

```
res = find( 'a', text: text, visible: true)
if ((res[:target] || '') == '_blank')
    @win = window_opened_by { res.click }
else
    res.click
end
```

I found out that if I change this to

```
find( 'a', text: text, visible: true).click
```

the message disappears and the scenario passes the test. Who can help me understanding what can be the problem here. Why is this failing when the find result is assigned to a variable and why is it only failing in only few situations?

I use ruby 2.4.0 and capybara-webkit 1.2.0

thanks, Ruud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't indicate exactly which line is generating the error (which one is line 64), however the error indicates that you're still using an element after it has been removed from the page, either by JS deleting the element or a new page being loaded.

Additionally the `visible: true` option really shouldn't be needed since that is normally the default value for the `visible` option (unless you've changed it which is a terrible idea when testing software, not as bad if just scraping sites)

Also - capybara-webkit 1.2.0 was released in July 2014 -- You REALLY want to update that to the latest release if you're testing anything even slightly modern, as well as probably updating your ruby to at least the latest 2.4.x release.

Comment: I upgraded capybara-webkit with bundle to the latest version bundle knows of, which is 1.15.0. I removed the visible option. After that, I get the same behaviour. Line 64 is the line on which the buttonis actually clicked, in the post 'res.click()'. Can it possibly have to do with the fact the clicked button opens a download dialog? I

Comment: upgrading ruby has no effect either.

Comment: @ruud I don't think it opening a download dialog should make a difference.  The only way this makes sense is if you're calling `follow_link_in_new_tab` while the page is changing and `res` is disappearing, but even that should just automatically reload `res` (unless you've done something silly like set `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` to a really small value).  Is this project publicly accessible so I can take a look?

Comment: hi thomas, in preparing the code for you I tried some different versions of it with lines disabled. It appeared some of them were working.

Comment: It turned out I had a wrong idea what was going on. I am ashamed to admit it, but the message was not caused by the res.click itself (as I assumed) but a verbose message after the click, accesing the res element. Normally this caused no problem, but I think because of the download dialog in this case the res elemnt was not attached to the DOM anymore. Thanks Thomas, without your help I wouldn't have found this.